# Chained paypal payment

Tags: paypal, method-chaining, chained

I was wondering, under PayPal [chained payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#id0937N0OK05Z) if I could be a secondary receiver and not receive paypal disputes?

Let me explain more:

Say I have a buyer and a seller and me.

I want the buyer to buy directly from the seller who will have a paypal account and automatically I will receive some commission from that payment.  However, I do not want to be the one the payment is made to as I do not want to be involved in disputes so I was wondering if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Have them authorize your API user ID to run calls on their behalf. Then you pass their primary email address as an argument in your calls and do your chained payment. You still get paid but they would "own" the payment. The downside is that if they lose the dispute, I bet they deduct form your account too...